# Can my 2 children, aged 10 and 12, who are US citizens, travel to the USA on expired American passports?

Tags: air-travel, us-citizens, passport-renewals

My children are 10 and 12 years old. They are US citizens (no dual citizenship). There is no consulate or embassy on the island where I live (Guadeloupe). To renew the children's passports, I need to travel to another island (Martinique) which is a bit costly.

Can my children travel to US using their expired passports?

Comment: For what it's worth, children under 16 can enter the US by sea from the Caribbean with any proof of citizenship, such as a birth certificate or consular report of birth abroad, though I suspect that sailing to the USVI, Puerto Rico, or Florida may be even more inconvenient than getting to Martinique.

Comment: Have you telephoned or written to the consulate in Martinique to ask for advice about this? Do they insist on an in-person appearance? Another possible source of information is the office of a senator from the state where you vote. This is called "constituent service" and senate offices have staff to do it.

Comment: I found the trip Martinique - Guadeloupe costs only $50, one-way. Is that costly?

Comment: @PierreB That adds up to $300, in addition to the cost of the new passports. So, it could be considered costly.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: that can definitively be costly under certain circumstances. I just wanted to make sure the OP had a similar figure in mind.

Comment: If they're citizens, they can enter the USA on a lightly used piece of toilet paper.  As citizens they can't be refused, that's what citizenship means. However a) airlines won't let someone fly on insufficient documentation; and b) CBP could delay them significantly, while it researches the veracity of their claim.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my questions.  I have spoken to the  consular in Martinique,  new laws mandate an in person appearance when applying for children's passport..I also have a 1 year old baby who breastfeeds,  I need my husband's help while travelling on the ferry with the children and all the vomiting which occurs.  The cost would be $400  plus the price of the passports as we need to return home.  And I have read all of your comments.   I'm considering passport cards instead of the traditional passport.  I will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 52):

If they manage to get to a port of entry, they should eventually be admitted, though it may not be a fun experience.

However **the airline** will almost certainly not let them board an international flight without valid passports, so what would happen on arrival is kind of moot.

Comment: +1. Denied boarding will probably cost OP more than the trip for passport renewal.

Comment: Does "how expired" impact it at all? Since they're minors, would it make a difference if the passports expired, for example, at the end of April and the travel was sometime in May? Technically/legally, I understand the answer is "no", however, would there _likely_ or even _possibly_ be leniency granted?

Comment: @FreeMan, why would an airline want to put themself at risk by being "lenient"? They wouldn't be able to provide truthful API for that flight, excluding themselves to hefty fines and possible withdrawal of their right to fly to the US at all.

Comment: @HenningMakholm because that's the kind of question that someone who finds himself in this kind of bind and doesn't have your knowledge of the rules & regulations might think of asking. Knowing that the answer is "no, they won't be lenient because it could come at a great cost to them", reduces the likelihood that said person will waste time & money on the hopes that they might be lenient. Many people have banked on that type of leniency, found it wouldn't happen, then come here looking for a solution after having wasted the time & money.

Comment: The airline may deny boarding even if the passport will *soon* expire, never mind an actually expired passport.

Comment: @chepner: I don't think any airline has a policy of denying boarding for passengers with soon-expiring passports _from the country they're flying to_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That may depend on "soon" perhaps. I am now thinking of expiry happening in-flight (or possbbly i flicght in case of possible delay) or in a differnt time zone :)

Answer (score 46):

US consulates, including the one in Barbados, offer [Consular Outreach Visits for U.S. Citizen Services](https://bb.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/consular-outreach-visits/):

> In order to better serve U.S. citizens living throughout the Eastern Caribbean, the U.S. Embassy in Barbados makes every effort to send a Consular Officer to countries in our Consular District approximately twice a year to offer certain American Citizen Services such as accepting applications for U.S. passports and Consular Reports of Birth Abroad, and provide notarial services.

I had a look through their events calendar and don't see anything coming up for Guadeloupe, but it would be worth asking them. The US citizens in my family have used this service in our part of the world and it is definitely more convenient than travel to the consulate location.

Comment: Looking at that calendar, it appears that the last such trip to Guadeloupe was in June 2018. If they're shooting for twice a year, they're way overdue.

Comment: This answer provides a useful tip on how OP can arrange for renewal at their place of residence but does not provide answer to the actual question ("Can the children travel with expired passports to the US")

Comment: Consular budgets are severely constrained these days.

Comment: @O.Jones But if the OP contacts them and indicates the need for a consular visit to Guadeloupe, they may schedule a visit they wouldn't otherwise.

Comment: I have contacted Barbados embassy.  I was told there is no consular travelling to Guadeloupe and was referred to Ms.  Leah Mcgraw Maurice in Martinique.