# Can my American children re-enter the USA by International flight with a passport card, as their passport book has expired?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, us-citizens

Their traditional passport book has expired. The consulate here is not giving me a solid reason why I need a more costly passport book. The Consulate says that passport cards are used by people crossing borders regularly from Canada or Mexico to the USA. Is this true? Can’t my children re-enter the USA with a passport card? They are American minors under the age of 13.

Comment: Where are you travelling from?

Comment: Also, do they have any other citizenship? Under what status are they in the country they currently are in? The issue with passport cards is they cannot get visas or stamps, so at the very least many foreign countries immigration authorities can’ Use them. Some airlines may also have difficulty recognising them.

Comment: @jcaron the other issue is that the US explicitly does not authorize its citizens to use them for international air travel, as covered in mkennedy's [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/138565/19400).  Other countries could unilaterally decide to recognize the card as valid ID for US citizens in the country, but that won't change the fact that no airline will board a passenger for an international flight to the US with (only) a passport card.

Comment: No airline will let you on a US bound plane with just a passport card. You  can potentially get in the country, but you won't be able to go on the plane in the first place

Comment: The US passport card can't be used for air travel, in part because it doesn't meet the ICAO standards for passport cards. This is why I chose not to get one until the US issues ICAO-compliant passport cards and they become usable for air travel.

Comment: Americans can re-enter the USA, *always*, full stop. But boarding a private company's plane is at the owner's discretion.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't think it's a technical issue with the passport card, but an issue with international agreements. Permanent residents can enter the US with only their green card, even by air.

Comment: @user71659 Well, there's that too. The US passport card doesn't qualify as a travel document under (most of) those agreements, and the technical matters are one reason why.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/137821/can-my-2-children-aged-10-and-12-who-are-us-citizens-travel-to-the-usa-on-exp (not duplicate, as this was OP's previous question, prior to visiting the consolate)

Comment: @user71659 I don't think it has anything to do with international agreements.  The passport card was introduced to allow people who used to be able to go to Mexico or Canada with a driver's license and possibly proof of citizenship to be able to continue to do that with a document of a similar cost and size.  The US unilaterally forbids its citizens from using it for international air travel.

Comment: @MichaelHampton what agreements are you thinking of?  I am unaware of any.

Comment: @phoog Yeah, thinking about it, it may be the fact that passport fees fund consular services and the passport card is cheaper because it funds only cheaper North American consulates. Otherwise the thing is that the US has no problem accepting a green card for entry, so it has no issue with the security or technical aspects of cards. The passport card was a result of WHTI which [does require](https://www.dhs.gov/news/2009/02/26/departments-homeland-security-and-state-certify-whti-criteria) that Canada and Mexico accept passport cards and EDLs, which typically involve reciprocity.

Comment: @user71659 before WHTI Canada and Mexico would accept any reasonable proof of identity and citizenship.  I once entered Canada on the basis of a US driver's license and a statement that I was born in the US.  But I am unaware of any agreement between Canada or Mexico wherein the other party has undertaken not to require passports for US citizens entering by land; as far as I can tell it's a unilateral decision in each case.  There's certainly no reciprocity for Mexicans, though the US does accept Canadian EDLs and I suppose it would accept Canadian passport cards if they existed.

Answer (score 23):

> The consulate here is not giving me a solid reason why I need a more costly passport book.

The relevant federal regulation is found at [8 CFR 235.1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/235.1).  It starts by saying that everyone needs a passport unless they qualify for one of several exceptions, found both in that part and at [22 CFR 53.2](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/53.2).  In addition to the exception for a passport card, there are exceptions applying to children under 19 or 16, depending upon the circumstances.  However, *all of these exceptions apply only for entry at a land or sea port of entry.*  They do not apply to international air travel.

The passport card exception is found at [8 CFR 235.1(b)(1)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/235.1#b_1):

> **Passport card.** A U.S. citizen who possesses a valid unexpired United States passport card, as defined in 22 CFR 53.1, may present the passport card when entering the United States from contiguous territory or adjacent islands at land or sea ports-of-entry.

The exceptions for children are found at [8 CFR 235.1(b)(8)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/235.1#b_8):

> (8) **Children.** A child who is a United States citizen entering the United States from contiguous territory at a sea or land ports-of-entry may present certain other documents, if the arrival falls under subsection (i) or (ii).
>
> (i) **Children under Age 16.** A U.S. citizen who is under the age of 16 is permitted to present either an original or a copy of his or her birth certificate, a Consular Report of Birth Abroad issued by the Department of State, or a Certificate of Naturalization issued by U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services when entering the United States from contiguous territory at land or sea ports-of-entry.
>
> (ii) **Groups of Children under Age 19.** A U.S. citizen, who is under age 19 and is traveling with a public or private school group, religious group, social or cultural organization, or team associated with a youth sport organization is permitted to present either an original or a copy of his or her birth certificate, a Consular Report of Birth Abroad issued by the Department of State, or a Certificate of Naturalization issued by U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services when arriving from contiguous territory at land or sea ports-of-entry [...]

The provisions at [22 CFR 53.2(b)(11)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/53.2#b_11) are essentially the same:

> (11) When the U.S. citizen is a child under the age of 19 arriving from contiguous territory in the following circumstances:
>
> (i) **Children under age 16.** A United States citizen who is under the age of 16 is permitted to present either an original or a copy of his or her birth certificate, a Consular Report of Birth Abroad, or a Certificate of Naturalization issued by U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services when entering the United States from contiguous territory at land or sea ports-of-entry; or
>
> (ii) **Groups of children under age 19.** A U.S. citizen who is under age 19 and who is traveling with a public or private school group, religious group, social or cultural organization, or team associated with a youth sport organization may present either an original or a copy of his or her birth certificate, a Consular Report of Birth Abroad, or a Certificate of Naturalization issued by U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services when arriving in the United States from contiguous territory at all land or sea ports of entry...

Now a US citizen cannot be denied entry to the US if the US citizen can get to the border and prove his or her US citizenship by any means.  The problem here is that the airline is not bound to transport US citizens based on any proof of citizenship; they are required to demand identification that meets the regulatory requirements.

Comment: I wonder what would happen at a pre-clearance location...

Comment: @jcaron I doubt they'd get to preclearance because they wouldn't get a boarding pass.  If the airline decided to ask the local officers about it, they would probably also decline to let them travel.  I suppose there might be a chance of getting them through, but I would be surprised if it succeeded.  A US citizen with dual citizenship posted here to say that she was not allowed to fly from Canada to the US with ESTA; it's not entirely clear, but it looks like she was given a boarding pass and then stopped by CBP at the passport checkpoint and told she had to get a passport.

Answer (score 14):

The problem has two layers.

**Being allowed into the country** -- they are US citizens.  They cannot be refused entry into the US.  However, immigration can detain them as long as is necessary to confirm their citizenship.  The passport card should cover this task, however you are technically are violating the law (as phoog discusses at length). Expect considerable delay and a stern lecture, finger-wag and possible fine.

**Being allowed to board an airplane** (or boarding pass in preclearance airports) -- the bigger problem is the airline may be fidgety about allowing you on board the plane, if your credentials are not in order. And  unlike CBP, they are not *obliged* to work with you, and they do not have all of CBP's resources to confirm your citizenship.  They also face serious financial penalties for not pre-checking your credentials.  As such, **they are likely to refuse to let you get on the airplane**.  This will get decided ad-hoc at the gate, without any sort of appeals process, and when you miss the plane, **you will eat the cost of the flight**.

Comment: The airline *is* in fact obliged *not* to board the passenger if so instructed by CBP during the exchange of passenger manifest information that occurs before the boarding pass is issued.  It's not just about "checking" the credentials; they transmit the credentials to CBP and get a message back telling them whether or not to let the person on the plane.  So it's more than likely that they'll refuse to let them board; it's certain.

Comment: @Phoog Would CBP really signal "do not board" for a person *they know* is a US citizen?

Comment: Would they signal "okay to board" for someone whose documents do not comply with federal regulations (nor with the statute)?  I do not think so.  As I noted in another comment, they seem to have prevented a dual citizen from flying from Canada to the US with her non-US passport and ESTA.  And this all assumes that the airline is willing and able to submit a passport card in the APIS transaction; there are probably procedures in place that prevent that, but I could not find them.

Comment: @phoog The reason I wonder, is it would mean *they are refusing someone they know they can't refuse at the border*.  That seems pretty underhanded, and possibly even illegal; usurping their right to enter.  I would guess their motivation is to enforce 8 CFR 235.1.

Comment: The [carrier guide](https://www.cbp.gov/document/guides/carrier-information-guide-english) does say "Under no circumstances can the U.S. Passport
Card be used as a substitute for a regular booklet-style passport."  I suppose a court might overturn the requirement, but a US citizen would have to go to court to make that happen, which seems unlikely, since getting a passport is a lot easier.

Comment: @phoog yeah and that's probably it; the government would argue that a US citizen is entitled to enter the US with nothing but their birthday suit, but CBP is entitled to identify them and define the manner in which they do; i.e. at a consulate not the airport. It'd be an arguable case, sorta like the IRS "illegal income"/frivolous return case.

Comment: Stern finger wagging and possibly (likely) a fee or fine. Have seen this.

Comment: @mickeyf I've never seen any evidence of a fee or fine, though I have heard something that suggests one may be in the works for land border crossings (w.r.t. the WHTI).  Have you seen anyone actually fined?

Comment: @mickeyf the proposed fee for travelers who do not comply with WHTI is at the proposed rule stage ([1651-AB06](https://www.reginfo.gov/public/do/eAgendaViewRule?pubId=201810&RIN=1651-AB06)), as it has been since [the Fall 2015 agenda](https://www.reginfo.gov/public/do/eAgendaHistory).  It appears to be worded in such a way that it would not apply to citizens who arrive in the US by air (for example, a dual citizen using a foreign passport), but as explained elsewhere that doesn't seem to be an option for this question.

Comment: @phoog Happened to us. $100 iirc. Mind you, 20 years back. Rules change.

Comment: @mickeyf where were you fined, and what documents did you have?  I entered the US without a passport once, with a driver's license and I don't remember what I said in the interview, but that was by land and 26 years ago.

Comment: That was pretty routine when crossing from the US to Canada.  I did it often enough on nothing but a driver's license, and less than that when I was a child.  Then, 9/11.

Comment: @mickeyf I found the $100 fee in the 1997 code of federal regulations (CFR).  It was changed to $0 between then and the CFR of 1998.  The regulation authorizing the fee was finally changed between 2006 and 2007.  The fee was only authorized for waiving the requirement under 22 CFR 53.2(h); entry from Canada was exempted separately under 22 CFR 53.2(b) (those references are to the CFR of 1997; things have been moved around since then and the 53.2(b) exemption substantially modified by the WHTI).

Answer (score 10):

Yes, they are correct. The passport card was designed for land and sea ports of entry and is not allowed for international air travel.

[Passport card page from the State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/card.html)